# Eigen template on scalar type

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I'm working on code with a lot of classes that template on a scalar type `T` and implement methods on containers like `std::valarray<T>`.  I'd like to add support for Eigen containers, but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to template only on the scalar type while maintaining some of Eigen's flexibility.

For example, the Eigen [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) suggest using `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>`, but that seems to mean I'd have to change all my class defintions to template on the array type `Derived` and then use `Derived::Scalar` everywhere.  Pretty intrusive just to support another container.

I could also just use `Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>`, but this is pretty restrictive.  For the cases I care about, I was thinking a reasonable middle ground would be to use `Ref<Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>>` since that would cover `Matrix` and slices thereof with one interface.  But this doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why.  Here's a concrete example of what I mean:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

double
sum1(const Ref<const Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic>> &m)
{
    double x = 0.0;
    for (int j=0; j<m.cols(); ++j)
        for (int i=0; i<m.rows(); ++i)
            x += m(i,j);
    return x;
}

template <typename T>
T
sum2(const Ref<const Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>> &m)
{
    T x = 0.0;
    for (int j=0; j<m.cols(); ++j)
        for (int i=0; i<m.rows(); ++i)
            x += m(i,j);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic> a(2,2);
    a << 0,2,1,3;
    cout << "sum1(a) = " << sum1(a) << endl;            // ok
    cout << "sum2(a) = " << sum2(a) << endl;            // error
    cout << "sum2(a) = " << sum2<double>(a) << endl;    // ok
    return 0;
}
```

But I get errors when I compile:

```
$ clang++  -std=c++17 -I/usr/include/eigen3   eig2.cpp   -o eig2
eig2.cpp:33:29: error: no matching function for call to 'sum2'
    cout << "sum2(a) = " << sum2(a) << endl;            // error
                            ^~~~
eig2.cpp:19:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Ref' against
      'Matrix'
sum2(const Ref<const Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>> &m)
^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to implement `sum2` so that it supports `Matrix` and `Ref` and doesn't require explicit template arguments to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that

```
template <typename T>
T
sum2(const Ref<const Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>> &m)
```

does not work for `Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>` is that C++ can't deduce template arguments and do type-conversion at the same time (`Ref` is a different type than `Matrix`, but it can be constructed with O(1) effort from it).

One alternative (requiring C++11 or higher) which allows you to keep the function body is:

```
template<typename Derived, typename T=typename Derived::Scalar>
T sum3(const MatrixBase<Derived> &m)
```

If you want to allow `Array` as well, you can use `DenseBase`, if you want to allow sparse matrices you can use `EigenBase`.

However, this is not equivalent to the `Ref` implementation with explicit type substitution, since if `Derived` is an expression, it may get evaluated multiple times inside your function.

An alternative is to write

```
template <typename T>
T
sum_impl(const Ref<const Matrix<T,Dynamic,Dynamic>> &m)
{ /* here comes the actual implementation */ }

template<typename Derived>
typename Derived::Scalar sum4(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& m)
{
    return sum_impl<typename Derived::Scalar>(m);
}
```